# @ConditionalOnExpression enabling/disabling @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to enable/disable controller depending on value in properties file. 
My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.enabled}")
public class Controller{
  public String getSomething() {
    return "Something";
  }
}
```

My properties file looks like this:

```
properties.enabled= false
```

And controller is always enabled (I can access method getSomething). I also tried combinations like this:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.enabled:true}")
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.enabled}==true")
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.enabled}=='true'")
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${properties.enabled}'=='true'")
```

Edit:
Also tried different annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "properties", name="enabled")
```

Comment: Use `@ConditionalOnProperty` instead or use an expression which should start with `#{...}` not `${...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem. This Bean wasn't created by Spring but in WebConfiguration class so i had to also add annotation there

```
public class CommonWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="properties",name = "enabled")
 public Controller controller() {
    return new Controller ();
 }
}
```

My Controller now looks like this:

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="properties",name = "enabled")
public class Controller{
  public String getSomething() {
   return "Something";
  }
}
```

Comment: do you need to keep that ConditionalOnProperty on a controller class?

Comment: I don't. Just forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do the same thing, but my Controller is created by spring and after I've added the annotation Controller is always disabled now. -_-

Comment: If your controller is created by Spring (not by your configurations), you need that ConditionalOnProperty if you want do something similar to this.